# Spring | Hibernate | Thymeleaf: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I am creating a form for adding new role entities to a database, and I am encountering the following error:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute
```

I've tried out several of the solutions for the same error here on StackOverflow, but none of them have worked. Shown below are my Role model and controller classes, as well as their associated template:

Role.java

```
@Entity
public class Role {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
  private List<Collaborator> collaborators = new ArrayList<>();

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
  private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();

  public Role() {
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public List<Collaborator> getCollaborators() {
    return collaborators;
  }

  public void setCollaborators(List<Collaborator> collaborators) {
    this.collaborators = collaborators;
  }

  public List<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
  }

  public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
  }
}
```

RoleController.java

```
@Controller
public class RoleController {
  @Autowired
  private RoleService roleService;

  @GetMapping("/roles")
  public String listRoles(Model model) {
    List<Role> roles = roleService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
    return "role/roles";
  }

  @PostMapping("/roles")
  public String addCategory(@Valid Role role, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.category", result);
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("role", role);
      return "redirect:/roles";
    }
    roleService.save(role);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Role successfully added!", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));
    return "redirect:/roles";
  }
}
```

roles.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head th:replace="layout :: head('roles')"></head>
    <body>
        <header th:replace="layout :: header"></header>
        <nav th:replace="layout :: nav"></nav>
        <div th:replace="layout :: flash"></div>
        <section>
            <div class="container wrapper">
                <form>
                    <h2>Manage Roles</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="checkbox-list">
                            <li th:each="role : ${roles}"><span class="primary" th:text="${role.name}">Role Name</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <form th:object="${role}" th:action="@{/roles}" method="post" class="actions add-new-role">
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Role Name"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
                    </form>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:401) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:328) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:294) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

**EDIT**: Thank you for helping to solve the problem.

Comment: when you remove id, is it working?

Comment: th:field="*{id}" can cause this error

Comment: Removing the ID field makes the name field the source of the problem: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'name' available as request attribute. Also, I need the ID field there, albeit hidden, as an autogenerated value.

Comment: oke can you change it with <input type="hidden" th:value="${role.id}" name="id" />

Comment: I understand your problem it is not about frontend

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez If I do that I get: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

Comment: oke when you first opened the page you go to get mapping and redirects to view. When you redirect a view you don't have ${role} object in the request attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162118/discussion-between-robert-valencia-and-gurkan-lleez).

Comment: You can iterate over roles then create multiple form elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up having two templates, an index of roles and a form for adding new role. I also have three controller methods: 2 get methods (1 for the index, 1 for the form), and 1 post methods (for adding new roles).

**RoleController.java**

```
@Controller
public class RoleController {
  @Autowired
  private RoleService roleService;

  // Index of roles
  @GetMapping("/roles")
  public String getRoles(Model model) {
    List<Role> roles = roleService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
    return "role/index";
  }

  // New role form
  @GetMapping("/roles/add")
  public String newRoleForm(Model model) {
    if(!model.containsAttribute("role")) {
      model.addAttribute("role", new Role());
    }
    model.addAttribute("action","/roles");
    model.addAttribute("heading","New Role");
    model.addAttribute("submit","Add");
    return "role/form";
  }

  // Add new role
  @PostMapping(value = "/roles")
  public String addNewRole(@Valid Role role, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.category",result);
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("role", role);
      return "redirect:/roles/add";
    }
    roleService.save(role);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Role successfully added!", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));
    return "redirect:/roles";
  }
}
```

**role/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head th:replace="layout :: head('roles')"></head>
    <body>
        <header th:replace="layout :: header('Role', '/roles/add')"></header>
        <div th:replace="layout :: flash"></div>
        <nav th:replace="layout :: nav"></nav>

        <section>
            <div class="container wrapper">
                <form>
                    <h2>Manage Roles</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="checkbox-list">
                            <li th:each="role : ${roles}"><span class="primary" th:text="${role.name}">Role Name</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div th:replace="layout :: scripts"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**role/form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head th:replace="layout :: head('roles')"></head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="site-header">
                <a class="logo" th:href="@{/}">InstaTeam</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div th:replace="layout :: flash"></div>
    <nav th:replace="layout :: nav"></nav>

    <section>
        <div class="container wrapper">
            <form th:action="@{${action}}" method="post" th:object="${role}">
                <h2 th:text="${heading}">New Role</h2>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
                <div class="actions add-new-role">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Role Name"/>
                    <button th:text="${submit}" type="submit" class="button">Add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div th:replace="layout :: scripts"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should confirm the id wasn't null before you use it , thymeleaf has problem when you use the value was null.

Comment: Hi the ID field is a generated value. By that did you mean I should add a @NotNull annotation to it?